# CompileSwift states "the current deployment target does not support automated __weak references" for iOS8.0

Tags: xcode, swift

I am endeavouring to use a static library (compiled from Objective C) from within a Swift app.

I have a single Objective C bridging header that includes the related headers. When building the app I get this error ..

```
/someDirectory/Xcode/FirstSteps/headers/Acme.h:89: the current deployment target does not support automated __weak references
```

The class Acme *does* use weak references, however the deployment target is iOS 8.0, which should support them. Am I barking up the wrong tree?

line 89 of Acme.h reads:

```
-(void) addTopicListener:(__weak NSObject<ACMETopicListenerDelegate>*) delegate;
```

Comment: Please post line 89 of Acme.h

Comment: I have the same issue (in escoz/QuickDialog) with an ivar tagged with __weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the answer is to remove the `__weak` attributes from the method argument, or in my case include this in my bridging header

```
#undef __weak
#define __weak /* nothing */
#import "Acme.h"
```

SwiftCompile apparently doesn't like the `__weak` attribute, and everything works fine without it. It does make me question the need for the `__weak` attribute on an *argument* in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure there are no consequences to this?

Comment: I also wonder if there are any side effects by disabling the __weak attribute, especially as the compiler has no problems with them (at least for ivars. I rather see this warning only in the debugger.